# How to name symbols for blind programmers

Tags: accessibility, camelcasing, pascalcasing

How should I name the symbols I write in a way that they are read correctly by screen readers, so they do not create a barrier for blind programmers? By "symbols" I mean things like variables and function names.

For example, if I write a variable name as `companyId`, would it be read correctly? Or writing it as `companyID` would be better?

Opinionated answers between casing styles are not what I want. I just want a technical point of view if I should type `HTTP` over `Http` or `Id` over `ID` in order to help screen readers to spell it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a blind programmer. Almost all screen readers do specialMixedCapsProcessing. That is, every capital letter will be pronounced as a new word.

One challenge that I face regarding identifier naming is that it can be tricky to spot two similar-sounding variables, particularly if the only difference is towards the end (when tired, my brain does pattern-recognition!). For example, numLinesInFile1/numLinesInFile2.

A related observation is that the _ character is often spoken as "underline", which is 3 syllabuls. This makes it less efficient IMHO to work with codebases where underlines_are_used. Some blind programmers rename "underline" to "line", but I find that confusing.

This is just one developer's opinion - other blind devs may have other ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know if I got it right, do you mean that I should type a name as `HttpConnection` (only first `H` capital) instead of `HTTPConnection` (all letters of `HTTP` capital)?

Comment: In this specific case, my screen reader pronounces both the same. Follow whatever is most common in your programming language of choice.